SASI support in Cassandra 3.11
we're running a 3.11.4 cassandra cluster with 3 nodes. The application team wants to create a SASI index on a clustering column, which has a high cardinality. The thing is that inside cassandra.yaml a comment saids this is an experimental feature but, apparently, there are projects which have using this configuration in prod environments when i google it. Can you help me to clarify this?
Can you give the main concerns if we decide to deploy it? The affected table has more than 52 million rows, and the idea is to expose this service to be consumed by a web service.
Could you please give me your opinion about this?
Thanks in advance,

The recommendation for the SSTable-Attached Secondary Index (SASI) has not changed ever since it was introduced in Cassandra 3.4 in 2016 (CASSANDRA-10661).
It has always been an experimental feature mostly since (a) it has not been tested exhaustively, and (b) it is not actively being worked on. In 2019, an opt-in flag was added:

enable_sasi_indexes from C* 3.11.5 (CASSANDRA-14866)
sasi_indexes_enabled from C* 4.1 (CASSANDRA-15234)

so developers cannot simply create SASI indexes without it being explicitly enabled on all nodes in the cluster (see discussion thread on the dev mailing list).
Some of the notable issues include:

OutOfMemoryError when using SASI (CASSANDRA-12662)
Confusing AND/OR semantics for SASI StandardAnalyzer (CASSANDRA-12674)
Multi-index query incorrectly returns 0 rows (CASSANDRA-13105)
Repair breaks SASI index (CASSANDRA-13403)
SASI sparse mode overflow corrupts SSTable (CASSANDRA-13478)
SASI query is not safe with concurrent compactions (CASSANDRA-15761)

The list of unresolved tickets is available on the project's Jira. Again, SASI is not actively developed so no one is working on these tickets.
With the phase 1 release of Storage-Attached Index (SAI) in Cassandra 5.0 (CASSANDRA-16052), the project will be adding more functionality to SAI in the future to mirror SASI features including the LIKE/OR operators, and global sorting (see Cassandra Enhancement Proposal CEP-7) so we don't recommend developing apps with SASI since it will possibly be deprecated soon in preference for SAI (personal opinion). Cheers!
